# How to inspect if flash banner does not spread malware or is harmful to site visitors?

Tags: advertising, flash, iframe, malware, banners

I would like to take a third party ad - flash banner on my site, I can place it as an iframe (to show a page with the banner, hosted on other domain), or I can host it myself.

I have seen, when browsing other sites, that sometimes my antivirus/anti malware software blocks the ads for being harmful...

I know that flash is quite shady thing as it is possible to use it for things of a dark side.

**Is there a good way of checking if flash banner has vulnerabilities, security holes or ways for the owner of it to target visitors of a site and spread malware or harm their computers?**

As I understand, if there is a 'hole' in it, the bad guy under control can target visitors just on a specific time, or for specific browsers, platforms, OS'es, mobiles, countries, etc.

Comment: Personally I would avoid flash altogether as it's pretty annoying for users. Why not use a static image?

Comment: Please answer on topic, as if going your lane, plain text is better than static image... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Researchers at the University of California released [a paper about how to detect malware in Flash files](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~vigna/publications/2012_RAID_flashdetect.pdf).